# linux network acceleration ,hardware offload

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, offloading

I am learning network hardware acceleration in Linux kernel for quiet a long time, but there still are several problems that make me very very confused. 
After deeply inspecting source code in kernel ,what confued me all the time are:

1.I can't clearly distinguish Flower offload, Flow offload, Flowtable offload, Flowtable HW offload.

2.What's the relationship between Flower offload and Flow offload? In driver implementation(kenerl 
  version 5.4), there always be both TC_SETUP_BLOCK and TC_SETUP_CLSFLOWER.
  As far as i know, TC_SETUP_CLSFLOWER indicates TC flower offload. Does TC_SETUP_BLOCK mean Flow 
  offload? If so, what is Flow offload? Is it netfilter offload?

3.Does flowtable offload mean a fast path for packet process implemented by software in kernel, while 
  flowtable HW offload means a fast path implemented by hardware?

Any one can help? Thanks very much.